# Cannot create an emulator with Android L (API 20)

Tags: android, eclipse, adt, emulation, android-5.0-lollipop

I have updated to ADT 23 and SDK manager with Android L (API 20 L preview), but I am not getting the "Android L" in the target list.

Done restarting the Eclipse many times. doesn't work. Some one please tell me what I am doing wrong.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Working now, as I have killed the process from the Task manager and restarted.

But had other problems. Hence I downloaded the latest version of Eclipse (Juno)+ Android sdk bundle which includes ADT 23 plugin.

Now Everything works fine.

Click [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html) to download.

Don't forget to set the configuration of your emulator of options Snapshots , Use host GPU unchecked .

Comment: For me it was vice versa: I checked Snapshots and it didn't work, changed back to Host GPU and everything worked fine.

Answer (score 18):

For those who are getting stuck at black screen:

Try enabling "Use Host GPU" while creating a device.

Comment: What is the reason behind that?

Comment: The "Use Host GPU" option uses the host computer's OpenGL implementation. Makes the emulator speed up, in this case starts the emulator.

Answer (score 1):

Before installing latest tools in SDK manager, try to update ADT plugin from Help -> Check for updates.

Then first you have to install latest SDK Tools, Platform-tools, and Build-tools.

After installing latest tools, you will get Android L and Android 4.4W sections:

**Follow below setps to Download the SDK**

1. Start the Android SDK Manager.
2. In the Tools section, select the latest Android SDK Tools, Platform-tools, and Build-tools.
3. Select everything under the Android L Developer Preview section and click Install packages...
4. Accept the Licensing Agreement for all of the packages and click Install.

Note: The Eclipse ADT plug-in requires Java 7 if your compilation target is the L developer preview.

Comment: Thank you @Priyank for your effort, I did all your steps already.

Answer (score 1):

The following configurations helped me created an Android L emulator successfully :

Device : Nexus 5

Target : Android L preview ( Ensure API 20 packages are installed as outlined in answers above )

CPU/ABI : Intel Atom  x86

Skin WQVGA400

RAM : 2048 VM Heap : 64

Emulation options Snapshots , Use host GPU unchecked .

The emulator took a while to load but was successful ultimately.

Answer (score 0):

Solution direct from forum -

There was a very recent change to Android Studio. It makes Android-L(API 20), which was announced today, the default target SDK. You are getting the error because it is searching for the Android-L and can't find it. Our lesson was prepared with Android KitKat (API 19) in mind.

Try installing:

**Android L (API 20, L Preview)**
SDK Platform Android L Preview
Intel x86 Atom System Image

and see if that fixes your problem. In light of the Android L Preview, we are working to assess what changes need to be made.

Here is solution for [error-failed-to-find-target-android-l](http://forums.udacity.com/questions/100199230/error-failed-to-find-target-android-l).