# Black screen on second activity on Android L emulator

Tags: android, android-emulator, android-5.0-lollipop

I am aware of the 'black screen problems' when starting Android L, see for example here:

[Cannot create an emulator with Android L (API 20)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452378/cannot-create-an-emulator-with-android-l-api-20)

We had this problem too, and solved it by activating the 'Use Host GPU' setting. After that, we were able to start up the emulator and debug our app.

**The main screen of the app appears to be fine, but as soon as we start another activity, a black screen appears.** While the black screen is on screen, we can always go back to the main activity by pressing the (soft / hardware) back button.

To be clear, our app runs fine on KitKat (emulators and devices).

**Any idea what could be wrong?**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the reason was that we were calling `setContentView(_view);` in `onResume()`.

As soon as we moved that call to `onCreate()`, everything was working as expected.

Comment: It was ur joava code issue then...NOT the emulator issue :) :(. Looks like a silly situation for you after you earned 1K+ reputation :)

Comment: Well the strange thing was that the same app was running okay in KitKat, and there was no error message in the L emulator.. maybe this answer helps someone else with the same problem.

Comment: Surely and chance for us to dig deeper into documentation if we can find something useful. Why don't u share your buggy code n working code here that other SO can help us understand

Comment: What part of the code do you want to see? The only thing we had to change was moving the `setContentView()` call to `onCreate()`. I don't know any part of the documentation that says you cannot set the content view in `onResume()`, so this is most likely a bug in Android L.

Comment: If you've already concluded that it is the bug with Android L then....that's cool. I just wanted a double check if we were missing something here and from your response it looks pretty straightforward scenario.

Answer (score 1):

When you start another activity, A Black Screen appearance is because of the time that your system is taking to render the next activity on to your emulator's screen with your new version.

Most of the times, it does happen to render the screen/layout/activity results in black screen for longer times and if you can kill all other unused processes and help make the system cache resource free that should result in making things work fine.

I observed this happens with 4.4L emulators but there is NO issue with Kitkat or other version Emulators as the present allocated cache is enough.

As you've also mentioned that your app is working fine with KitKat version Emulator and with 4.4L you are seeing this issue but able to go back/homee without issues..the above might be the reason.

Another solution to this is in yoru HAXM settings, you can allocate more system cache than the existing and try to see if the problem goes. I've done this. Earlier, I've allocated 4GB Cache for Intel HAXM but increated to 6GB now and things look pretty cool as of now :)

Comment: So you're saying that the black screen should disappear after a while? Unfortunately that isn't the case. The black screen stays for several minutes.

Comment: How long did I check? Did u try restarting the emulator and observer ? Did u also check system cache status during ?

Comment: Yes I checked that.. unfortunately the black screen was still there after ten minutes.

Comment: Can u try delete that AVD and recreate another AVD and see? Sometimes that helps