# Is it possible to get system image for Android API 20 for Android Studio Android emulator?

Tags: android, android-studio, android-emulator

I'd like to test my app on Android emulator for that API version, but it doesn't appear anywhere on AVD manager.

It looks there might be some issues that would avoid it to run, like shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24452378/cannot-create-an-emulator-with-android-l-api-20), but before that I've checked [the webpage that shows what looks like all available system images to emulate an Android API that are available from the AVD manager](http://123.15.57.34/android/repository/sys-img/google_apis/?C=N;O=D) and... it just looks like that for some reason API 20 isn't available. For some reason it jumps from 21 to 19. So whatever was said in that question doesn't look to be for use any longer.

Is there any way to be able to get that API version and install it in Android Studio so an emulator with that APi version can be created?

Comment: API Level 20 is first-generation Android Wear. It was not used for phones, tablets, or other form factors. Many of those devices were later updated to newer versions of Android Wear/Wear OS. So, unless you are writing an app for a wearable, API Level 20 is not useful to you.

Comment: Thanks, @CommonsWare, it' not for a wearable, so I don't need it.

Comment: That's why Google doesn't make it readily available. There are ways to get API Level 20 images IIRC (probably by checking a "show obsolete versions" checkbox somewhere in the SDK Manager), but there are *so* many API levels that Google has taken to filtering the roster to a subset that are likely to be used.